# Failed to start an Appium session

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, appium

Below error occour while trying to run Appium server via Intellij IEDA:

error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk""

> Failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]
>
> info: [debug] Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk""
>
> Failed to install C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install io.appium.settings without first uninstalling.]

I have tried via `gradel` and `maven`, same error for both!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the old app in the device and start the appium server again